# random walk with possibility to freeze

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk, law-of-large-numbers

Consider a Random Walk on a one-dimensional lattice. The walker starts moving at time $0$ from $x=0$. At every step, the walker moves to the right with probability $p$, to the left with probability $q$ and it dies with probability $r$. Naturally $p+q+r = 1$. What is the probability that it will reach the site $x=d$ before dying?

Comment: take simple random walk with up prob $\frac p {p+q}$ and kill it at each step with prob r.  This is your random walk. As the killing is independent of the random walk, the prob that it survives to hit d given that it takes T step to hit it is $r^T$, and the unconditional prob is the expected value of that, which is the moment generating fctn of the hitting time, which can be found as an exercise in many books, say, Karlin & Taylor vol 1.

Comment: Replace $r^T$ in @mike's comment by $(1-r)^T$ but, apart from that, just follow the signs!